# react-admin label prop does not work when creating custom fields

Tags: react-admin

I have created a simple wrapper component for `ReferenceField` in `react-admin` app:

```js
import {FC} from "react";
import {ReferenceField, ReferenceFieldProps} from "react-admin";

export const UserReference: FC<Omit<ReferenceFieldProps, "reference" | "label">> = (props) => {
    return <ReferenceField {...props} label="User" reference="users" />;
};
UserReference.displayName = "UserReference";
```

But when using the field the label is still inferred from `source` property (which is the default).
When I directly use `ReferenceField` with label it works:

```js
// UserReference renders label "User id" and ReferenceField renders correct "User"
<Datagrid>
  <UserReference source="user.id" />
  <ReferenceField reference="users" label="User" source="user.id" /> 
</Datagrid>
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?
Do I have to forward refs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Datagrid>` inspects its children label prop to build the header row. So to make it work in your case, you have to define the label in the `defaultProps`:

```
import {FC} from "react";
import {ReferenceField, ReferenceFieldProps} from "react-admin";

export const UserReference: FC<Omit<ReferenceFieldProps, "reference" | "label">> = (props) => {
    return <ReferenceField {...props} reference="users" />;
};
UserReference.displayName = "UserReference";
UserReference.defaultProps = { label: 'User' };
```

this is documented in the react-admin documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component